# Не получается вставить виджет внутрь другого виджета

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qlayout, pyowm

У меня есть небольшая программа, в которой есть **`четыре`** страницы, и я хочу вставить в четвертую страницу виджет с погодой.
Однако виджет не появляется внутри четвертой страницы, а появляется в виде нового окна и я не понимаю почему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот основной код, в который надо вставить виджет:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from main import App                              


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(845,535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        # Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)


        
        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
                
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('солнышко.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('папочка.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      
        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        #1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: green; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

        # page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               

        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')


        self.main = App()
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.main)
       
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
        # verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        # verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
  
        # календарь
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 381))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12,))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Вот код виджета, который надо вставить:

[**Чтобы виджет работал нужны еще несколько файлов, которые я загрузил в яндекс диск**](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/tQO7uxKqa_MEHg)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtTest, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import weather
import time
import datetime
from weather import DAYS 

#два класса с числами Фобаначе , для правного визуала 
H_show = [
    155,156,157,158,
    160,168,181,202,
    236,291,380,400,
    440,500,535,
]
H_hide = [
    155,156,157,158,
    160,168,181,202,
    236,291,380,400,
    440,500,535,
]

class WeatherData(QThread):
    req = weather.today()
    temp = req['temp']
    feels = req['feels']
    pres = req['pressure']
    speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
    city = req['city']
    type = req['dis']

    week = weather.week()

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                req = weather.today()
            except:
                req['temp'] = self.temp
                req['feels'] = self.feels
                req['pressure'] = self.pres
                req['wind']['speed'] = self.pres
                req['city'] = self.city
                req['dis'] = self.type

            try:
                req_week = weather.week()
                self.week = req_week
            except:
                self.week = DAYS

            self.temp = req['temp']
            self.feels = req['feels']
            self.pres = req['pressure']
            self.speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
            self.city = req['city']
            self.type = req['dis']
            time.sleep(600)


class App(QWidget):
    show_more = True 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weather = WeatherData()
        self.weather.start()
        
        self.set()
        self.setData()
        self.setMore()
 
    def set(self):
        self.w_root = uic.loadUi('root.ui')
        self.w_root.installEventFilter(self)
        self.w_root.btn_more.clicked.connect(self.setHeight)
        self.w_root.show()

    # перемещение кнопки с ресайзом
    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        self.w_root.resize(444, self.w_root.height())
        self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, self.w_root.height()-26)
        self.w_root.l_day.move(8, self.w_root.height()-18)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        return False

    #устанавливаем значение на сегодня
    def setData(self):
        # данные погоды
        self.w_root.l_temp.setText(str(self.weather.temp) + '°C')
        self.w_root.l_fell.setText(self.weather.feels)
        self.w_root.l_pres.setText(self.weather.pres)
        self.w_root.l_wind.setText(self.weather.speed + 'м/с')
        self.w_root.l_city.setText(self.weather.city)
        self.w_root.l_type.setText(self.weather.type)

        #иконка погоды
        px_logo = QPixmap(f'C:/python/pogoda/{self.weather.type}.png')
        self.w_root.l_logo.setPixmap(px_logo)

        #день недели
        today = DAYS[datetime.datetime.today().weekday()]
        self.w_root.l_day.setText(today['title'])
        color = today['color']
        self.w_root.l_day.setStyleSheet(f'color:{color}')

    def setHeight(self):
        if self.w_root.height() >= 200:
            self.show_more = False
        if self.show_more:
            for i in H_hide:
                if self.w_root.height() > i:
                    continue
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
                time.sleep(.02)
            self.show_more = False
        else:
            for i in reversed(H_show):
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
                time.sleep(.02)
            self.show_more = True
        App.show_more = self.show_more

    def setMore(self):
        for i in self.weather.week:
            w_day = uic.loadUi('day.ui')
            w_day.setObjectName('w_day_' + str(i['num']))
            w_day.l_title.setText(i['title'])
            w_day.l_temp.setText(str(round(i['temp'])) + '°C')
            w_day.l_type.setText(i['type'])
            w_day.l_title.setStyleSheet('color: ' + i['color'] + '; background-color: none; border: none')
            if i['active']:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid' + i['color'])
            else:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: none')
            self.w_root.box.addWidget(w_day)
        self.w_root.box.addStretch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу проверить код виджета, который вам надо вставить, но я вставляю что-то свое и все работает. Проверьте еще раз:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from main import App                                                  # ---
from pyowm_OWM import ExampleApp                                       # <---+++ 

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(845,535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        # Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)
        
        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
                
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('ball.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('lena.jpg'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

               
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))


        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        #1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: green; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

# page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
        
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')

#        self.main = App()
        self.main = ExampleApp()                                       # <----+++ 
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.main)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
        # verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        # verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
   
        # календарь
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 381))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12,))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**pyowm_OWM.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyowm                                                  # pip install pyowm

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Показать температуру', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_weather)  
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("Kiev", self, placeholderText='Введите город')
        self.lineEdit.move(100, 100)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("""
            QTextBrowser {
                background: #282928;            
                border: 3px solid #F77;
                border-radius: 10px;
                color: #fff;
            }
        """)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1)

    def get_weather(self):
        owm = pyowm.OWM('7c6d5748acf9ac9cc2f17c86e1111111')           # <--- ваш токен
        place = self.lineEdit.text()
        observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
        w = observation.get_weather()
        temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
        self.textBrowser.append(f'Температура  в {place}: { temp }')
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = ExampleApp()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

Попробуйте в вашем коде заменить строку:

```
self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.main)
```

на строку:

```
self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.main.w_root)
```

Также добавил пару принтов, покажите что они выводят, если не получится.

```
    ...
    self.main = App()                                       # <----+++ 
    
    print(f'self.main --> {self.main}')
    print(f'self.main.w_root --> {self.main.w_root}')
    
    #  self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.main)           # ---
    self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.main.w_root)       # <----+++ main.w_root
    
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)
    ...
```

Comment: Проверил, виджет с погодой все еще появляется как отдельное окно, а не внутри страницы. Еще попробовал ваш код и получил ошибку: 'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_place'

Comment: ответьте пожалуйста

Comment: @ivapop у меня пока нет предложений что вам еще попробовать, хотя попробуйте убрать `self.w_root.show()` в коде, который вы вставляете - что вы при этом будите наблюдать?

Comment: виджет с погодой просто не появился

Comment: @ivapop виджет с погодой просто не появился как отдельное окно - так? 
и не появляется когда вы нажимаете кнопку `btn_page_4` ? 
Я добавил в свой ответ, что вам надо еще попробовать - проверьте это.

Comment: Проверил, все работает, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ivapop пожалуйста